# Does Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 disable creating visual C++ projects?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I recently installed VS2010 beta 2 and tried to create a new Visual C++ project.  I enter the project name but the OK button is disabled so I cannot create it.  I could not find any documentation online about this experience.

Does VS2010 beta 2 block users from creating new Visual C++ projects, or is my installation at fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like an installation issue. I have not had the problem.

Comment: Yep.  I installed on a clean machine & it worked.  Must be a defect somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely an installation issue - they have spent extensive amounts of effort on improving C++ development in vs2010.

Doesn't mean its not a bug though!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried, worked for me. Is your projects folder writeable and did you make sure you have a valid Project Name and Solution Name? You can't have any characters that are reserved by the file system.